# typescript : type check optional parameter in a Function passed as arguments

Tags: typescript, typechecking

Here is the code:
(question follows)

one file contains this (types.ts)

```
declare global{
    interface AnInterface{
    }
}

export type SomeType<T> = 
    T extends [infer A, infer B] ?
      (fst: A, snd:B) => Promise<B> 
        : never

export async function accept<Z extends keyof AnInterface>(aKey: Z, fn : SomeType<Parameters<AnInterface[Z]>>){
    //do sthg with fn
    const firstArg : any = 1;
    const secondArg : any = 2;
    const fnAsAny = <any>fn;
    const result = await fnAsAny(firstArg,secondArg);
    console.log(result)
}
```

and in another file ("consumer.ts")

```
import {accept} from './types';

declare global{
    interface AnInterface{
        one : typeof fone 
        two : typeof ftwo
        three : typeof fthree
        four : typeof ffour
    }
}

export async function fone(a:number, b:number){return a+b;}
export async function ftwo(a:any, b:string){return a+b;}
export async function fthree(a:string, b:number=1){return b;}
export async function ffour(a:string){}


a: accept("one", fone); // OK
b: accept("two", fone); // ERROR BUT ... is expected: Argument of type '(a: number, b: string) => Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(fst: string, snd: string) => Promise<string>'.
c: accept("two", ftwo); // OK
d: accept("three", fthree); // Argument of type '(a: string, b?: number) => Promise<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
e: accept("four", ffour); // Compile Error but would like to pass
```

I would like to define type `SomeType<T>` so that line labeled **d and e** would pass the typescript check.
Is this possible? problem I have is with optional parameter, for case **e**, I could add another conditional type check.

Typescript : v 4.1

Comment: What is the purpose of `SomeType<T>`?  If you replace `fn: SomeType<Parameters<Z>>` with just `fn: Z` you will pass the checks which you want to pass.  And you no longer need to specify `Z` when calling `accept` since it can be inferred.  What am I missing?

Comment: @LindaPaiste : you are right, I was not clear on usage, I updated the snippets to more reflect the desire. note fone, ftwo, three,four must have max two arguments and I would like the second to be an optional one

Answer (score 0):

I've got a simple definition that works for all of your cases, with a small caveat regarding `ffour`.

We want a function that takes up to two arguments. The second argument could be optional or could be omitted entirely.  The function returns a `Promise` of the type of the second argument.

```
type MyFunc<A, B> = (a: A, b: B) => Promise<B>;
```

In the type itself, we state that `B` is required.  This is because a function with optional arguments `extends` one with required arguments, but not the other way around.  If `B` were optional in the type, then we could never fulfill that contract with a function that had a required second argument.

Note that a function with 0 arguments would pass because it's okay to have a function with less arguments than expected, but not more.

We make a dummy function which does nothing to see if our test cases will be accepted as arguments.

```
const checkFunc = <A, B>(func: MyFunc<A, B>): void => {}
```

```
// pass with 2 required args
checkFunc(
    async (a: number, b: number) => a + b
);
// pass with 2 requied args of different types
checkFunc( 
    async (a: any, b: string) => a + b
);
// pass with optional second argument
checkFunc(
    async (a: string, b: number = 1) => b
);
// FAIL as expected with more than 2 arguments
checkFunc(
    async (a: number, b: number, c: number) => a + b + c
)
```

If there is no second argument, then what is our return type?  Can it be `any` -- since we could call the function with any ignored second argument -- or can it only ever be `undefined`?  This is a question of expected behavior so there is no right or wrong answer.

As currently written, single-argument function will pass with `any` return type as the value of the second argument is `unknown`.

```
// pass with void function of single argument
checkFunc (
    async (a: string) => {}
)
// pass with function of single argument returning a value
checkFunc (
    async (a: string) => a
)
```

However we can change the signature of the function to enforce that only `void`/`undefined` can be returned.

```
// FAIL when returning a value with second argument explicitly disallowed
checkFunc (
    async (a: string, b?: never) => a
)
```

We can also force failure by explicitly setting the generics of `checkFunc` rather than allowing them to be inferred.

```
// FAIL based on generics <string, never> -- must have <string, string> to pass
checkFunc<string, never> (
    async (a: string) => a
)
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/YmpR7w)

Comment: @ LindaPaiste do you suggest replacing SomeType<T> with type `MyFunc<A, B> = (a: A, b: B) => Promise<B>` because I only know Z, which is the key in the merged interface AnInterface and with that key, I take the Parameters of the type of that key in the interface (Parameters<AnInterface[Z]>) which result in an array which I assume to be an array of two parameters